# Why are the titles in a master detail page not shown on android (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `MasterDetailPage` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MY_App.screens.MainScreen">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Master Title">
      <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Button Text="Label Button"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage Title="Detail Title">
      <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                    Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                    WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
      </ContentPage.Padding>
      <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label  Text="Heading"/>
          <Button Text="Master Button"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And on android it looks like this:

[image]

Why is non of the titles showing?

**Update** Following  the answer from yuri-s I get this:

[image]

Now I am wondering, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change master title (it uses Activity title) though you have to define it. But here is how to set Details title.

```
 <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
    <ContentPage Title="Detail Title">
      <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                    Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                    WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
      </ContentPage.Padding>
      <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label  Text="Heading"/>
          <Button Text="Master Button"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It still does not work here, I updated my question.

Comment: Do you push your MasterPage inside Navigation page or inside another MasterPage?

Comment: Oh ... I do. Ok, so I did not give all the details, sorry. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check in App.cs class you're instantiating correctly the MainPage

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new Views.MasterDetailView();
}
```